# Reproducción de video desde un recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

tengo 2 videos en mi carpeta raw que muestro con un recyclerview, la idea es que el usuario elija cual reproducir, haga click y se reproduzca  y no logro hacerlo, entiendo que debería tener una referencia de mi videoview dentro de mi holder donde capturo la posición en la lista del video, pero no se como pasarlo al setVideoURI... alguna sugerencia?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recycler;
VideoView video;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(DatosRaw.allRawFiles());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    //********************************VIDEO*****************************************
    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    video.setMediaController(mc);
    video.stopPlayback();
}
}
```

AdapterDatos.java:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {


    holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    final int pos = position;

    holder.dato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        posicionmarcada = pos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if (posicionmarcada==position){


        listDatos.get(position);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendes bien esto que comentas:

> "entiendo que debería tener una referencia de mi videoview dentro de
> mi holder"

En tu clase "Holder" obtén la referencia del `VideoView`:

```
public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        VideoView videoView;
        ...
        ...
        public ViewHolderDatos(View itemView) {

            videoView = (VideoView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
```

En el listener del

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {


    holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    final int pos = position;

    holder.dato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        posicionmarcada = pos;

       //Obtiene y reproduce video
       int rawVideoId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(listDatos.get(position),  "raw", context.getPackageName());
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + rawVideoId;
        holder.videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        holder.videoView.start();

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if (posicionmarcada==position){


        listDatos.get(position);

    }
}
```

---

**Como obtener el contexto dentro del Adapter.**

La forma de obtener el contexto en este caso la activity dentro de un Adapter es enviarlo al constructor :

```
private Context context;

public AdapterDatos(Context context, .....){
    this.context = context;
    ...
    ....
}
```

para enviar el contexto puedes inicializar el `Adapter` desde la `Activity` de esta forma :

```
AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(this, DatosRaw.allRawFiles());
```

Comment: Gracias Jorge,  estoy aprendiendo android y no sabia como implementarlo, ahora tengo un problema de contexto creo yo porque no puedo usar getResources() ni getPackageName, etc, como puedo corregir este error?

Comment: Tienes razón @Carlos , se necesita el contexto, modifique la respuesta.

Comment: Genial Jorge, lo voy a probar, muchas gracias